# Why is my Ember Observer firing before the computed property on which it depends?

Tags: ember.js

If I have an Observer ("child") that depends only on a CP ("parent"), is there any reason that the child function would ever be triggered/run before the parent? That seems to be what I'm seeing when I update one of the props that the parent depends on...

Some more details:

- the observer has `.on('didInsertElement')`
- the parent CP is (indirectly) consumed by the template
- on initial render, i see the the CP function run first, then the observer
- when updating one of the props the CP depends on, i see the observer running first, then the CP

When I say the parent CP is "indirectly" consumed by the template, what I mean is it's actually two dependent CPs of the parent CP that are directly consumed in the template, not the parent itself. But both of those functions fetch the parent CP, so I'm pretty sure that should have the same effect -- the parent CP first gets consumed during the initial render

Here's a simplified example of the component in question to hopefully make 
this a bit more clear:

```
import Ember from 'ember';

 export default Ember.Component.extend({
  didInsertElement() {
    console.log('didInsertElement called');
  },
  didRender() {
    console.log('didRender called');
  },
  parentCP: Ember.computed('someOtherProp.[]', function() {
    console.log('called parentCP')
    return something;
  }),
  myObserver: function() {
    console.log('called observer');
    this.get('parentCP');
    // ... do something
  }.observes('parentCP').on('didInsertElement'),
  childCP1: Ember.computed('parentCP', function() {
    console.log('called child CP 1');
    this.get('parentCP');
    // ... compute
  }),
  childCP2: Ember.computed('parentCP', function() {
    console.log('called child CP 2');
    this.get('parentCP');
    // ... compute
  }),
});
```

Here's the sequence on initial render:

- first child CPs is called
- parent is called (presumably when the child fetches it)
- second child is called (and seems to use the cached parent CP val)
- observer of the parent fires

(this is basically what I'd expect)

When I add an element to `someOtherProp`, though, the sequence looks like this:

- observer of parent CP
- parent CP
- child CP 1
- child CP 2

Is this what's expected? two things in particular:

1. the out-of-order observer firing is really surprising
2. I'd have thought the order of parent and child CPs would be the same as before (ie that the parent CP wouldn't be recomputed until one of the children fetched it), but it seems that it's getting recomputed non-lazily

￼￼￼
(to be clear, #2 is not actually that surprising, but just not how I thought CPs worked)

Answer (score 2):

As explained to me by @locks in the Ember slack:

This is expected, because observers are eager: they fire as soon as there are any changes to props that their dependencies depend on

And, because in this case the Observer accesses the parent CP, it causes it to trigger next. That result is cached, and then used later by the two child CPs